# Using ApplyEdits in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing

In my ArcGIS Javascript 3.12 application I am drawing a freehand polygon, clicking a "Save" button and adding the polygon to my feature layer.  This works correctly except when the polygon crosses itself (Image 1).

When the polygon crosses itself and save is clicked, the success function runs and everything appears to be working.  When I open the attribute table in ArcMap to look at the polygon it has "empty" spatial values (Image 2).

Does anyone have any ideas?

I can provide code samples if needed.

**Image 1**

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

up until yesterday you would have had to invoke a web request to a [geometry service](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html) to validate the topological correctness of your feature before passing the edit, but as of 3.13 you can now use the local geometry engine and call [simplify()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengineasync-amd.html#simplify)

Comment: Thanks John, it will be interesting to explore the new geometry engine in 3.13.

Comment: I tried using the simplify() method from the geometryEngine and was thrown an error.  What are the requirements for the geometry object passed in this method?

Comment: not sure.  i can't reproduce what you're reporting: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/simplify.html

Comment: Yeah I think it was another issue on ym end, thanks